# in xslt how to compare a string value with another variable containing multiple values

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml file. I need to fetch all unique "owner" values from this and perform some operations.

```
<issues>
<issue>
<owner>12345</owner>
</issue>
<issue>
<owner>87654</owner>
</issue>
<issue>
<owner>12345</owner>
</issue>
</issues>
<tests>
<test>
<owner>34598</owner>
</test>
<test>
<owner>12345</owner>
</test>
<test>
<owner>34598</owner>
</test>
<test>
<owner>11111</owner>
</test>
</tests>
```

I tried using following xslt script.

```
<xsl:for-each select="issues/issue[not(child::owner=preceding-    sibling::issue/owner)]/owner">
<!--some code-->
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="tests/test[not(child::owner=preceding- sibling::test/owner)]/owner">
<xsl:variable name="IrmAs">
<xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="IssueList">
<xsl:value-of select="//issues/issue/owner">
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:if test="not(contains($IssueList,$IrmAs))">      
<!--some code-->
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But am getting duplicate values. Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 you can just use `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="issues/issue | tests/test" group-by="owner">
  <!-- in here, . is the first issue/test with a given owner and current-group()
       is the sequence of all issue/test elements that share the same owner -->
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

If you are stuck on 1.0 then you need to use a technique called "Muenchian grouping" - define a *key* that groups elements with the same owner, then process just the first item in each group using a `generate-id` trick

```
<xsl:key name="ownerKey" match="issue | test" use="owner" />

<xsl:for-each select="(issues/issue | tests/test)[generate-id()
               = generate-id(key('ownerKey', owner)[1])]">
  <!-- one iteration per unique owner, with . being the parent element of the
       first occurrence -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you. Am new to xslt.Am using xslt1.0 Also could you please let me know where I went wrong in my above script. $IssueList contains all owner values of Issues. Why "not(contains($IssueList,$IrmAs))" doesn't work in this case? I know I might be horribly wrong.But it would be really helpful if you clarify.

Comment: Read the spec of contains(). You're imagining it tests whether a node-set contains a particular value. It actually does something quite different. The way to test whether a node-set contains a particular value is with the "=" operator.

Answer (score 0):

> But am getting duplicate values.

It's not quite clear *where* you are getting the duplicate values - since your posted code does not output anything. If you had tested something like:

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="issues/issue[not(child::owner=preceding-sibling::issue/owner)]/owner">
    <out>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </out>
</xsl:for-each>
....
```

you would have seen that it *does* work (albeit inefficiently) and returns:

```
...
<out>12345</out>
<out>87654</out>
...
```

Similarly, testing the following snippet:

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="tests/test[not(child::owner=preceding-sibling::test/owner)]/owner">
    <xsl:variable name="IrmAs">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="IssueList">
        <xsl:value-of select="//issues/issue/owner"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="not(contains($IssueList,$IrmAs))">  
        <out>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </out>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

produces:

```
...
<out>34598</out>
<out>11111</out>
...
```

So the problem must be in the part of the code that you haven't posted. Note also that the code you did post has several syntax errors, e.g. :

```
<xsl:value-of select="//issues/issue/owner">
```

needs to be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//issues/issue/owner"/>
```